# Get distinct array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, arraylist

Distinct array of objects as like below; i want to get unique array of objects.

Example Array:

```
const data = [ { "name": "abc", age: "31", project: "Java" }, { "name": "abc", age: "31", project: "Java" }, { "name": "abc", age: "29", project: "Javascript" }, { "name": "abc", age: "31", project: "C++" }, { "name": "abc", age: "31", project: "Java" }, { "name": "abc", age: "31", project: "Java" }]
```

Expected Output:

```
const data = [ { "name": "abc", age: "31", project: "Java" },{ "name": "abc", age: "29", project: "Javascript" }, { "name": "abc", age: "31", project: "C++" }]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Comment: Do you consider `{a:5, b:6}` to be the same as  `{b:6, a:5}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let unique = [...new Set(data.map(i => JSON.stringify(i)))].map(i => JSON.parse(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach enforces a consistent key order, and uses JSON.stringify on each object to test for uniqueness.

```js
const data = [ { "name": "abc", age: "31", project: "Java" }, { "name": "abc", age: "31", project: "Java" }, { "name": "abc", age: "29", project: "Javascript" }, { "name": "abc", age: "31", project: "C++" }, { "name": "abc", age: "31", project: "Java" }, { "name": "abc", age: "31", project: "Java" }]

const result = [...new Set(data.map(i=>JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(i).sort(([a],[b])=>a.localeCompare(b))))
))].map(JSON.parse)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your data, `project` property is containing dynamic values. Hence, You can filtered out the duplicates with in a single line of code by using [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const data = [ { "name": "abc", age: "31", project: "Java" }, { "name": "abc", age: "31", project: "Java" }, { "name": "abc", age: "29", project: "Javascript" }, { "name": "abc", age: "31", project: "C++" }, { "name": "abc", age: "31", project: "Java" }, { "name": "abc", age: "31", project: "Java" }];

const uniq = {};

var arrFiltered = data.filter(obj => !uniq[obj.project] && (uniq[obj.project] = true));

console.log(arrFiltered);
```